# Serialize and Deserialzie back list of interface with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism

I have two simple classes - Cat and Dog, each of them implements interface Pet.

My goal is to serialize and deserialize back a list of Pets.

I've read manuals about Jackson's polymorhic features along with other SO threads: 
http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Apperently, I'm missing some important part of it.

While serialization works fine:

```
Serialized pets: 
[{"type":"cat","name":"Oscar"},{"type":"dog","name":"Spot"}]
```

Deserialization throws Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `testProj.Cat` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

My SSCCE:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //-------------------           
        //---serialize-------
        //-------------------

        List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        pets.add(new Cat("Oscar"));
        pets.add(new Dog("Spot"));

        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(pets);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Serialized pets: ");
        System.out.println(json);

        //-------------------           
        //----deserialize----
        //-------------------

        List<Pet> deserializedPets = null;
        try {
            deserializedPets = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Pet>>() {});
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        for (Pet pet : deserializedPets) {
            System.out.println(pet);
        }
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
      @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"), 
      @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") 
    })
interface Pet {

}

class Cat implements Pet {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = "cat";
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cat [type=" + type + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

class Dog implements Pet {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = "dog";
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog [type=" + type + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```